# How to query reverse foreign key in django?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I am trying to filter queryset for a reverse foreign key.
Here are my two models:-

```
class BranchModel(basemodel.BaseModel):
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="Head Office")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='branch_owner')

class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False
    )
    objects = UserManager()
```

I want to get all the users of a branch.
I tried to use this queryset:-

```
User.objects.filter(branchmodel__user=self.request.user)
```

but it is giving me empty result.
how can i modify this?

Comment: So exactly what `User`s do you want to retrieve? Since a `BranchModel` here points with a `ForeignKey` to an `Owner`, this means that there is *one* user linked to a `BranchModel`, not multiple ones.

Comment: Is there another relation from `User` to `BranchModel` that is not in this code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want all branches of user as per your model setup. Below code will gives you all branches of request.user

```
user=self.request.user
prtnt(user)  # to check user in terminal
userbranches=user.branch_owner.all()
```